# Position form field in bottom of div

Tags: html, css, forms, css-position

I want to place a form field(div.invoer) in the left bottom of a div(div.content)

```
<body>
 <div id="container" style="width:1280px";"height:800px">

   <div id="header" style=;"background-color:#FFA500;""width:1280px";"height:200px">
     <h1>EXPORT ZENDINGEN</h1>
   </div>

   <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:600px;width:700px;float:left;">

   </div>

   <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:600px;width:580px;float:right;">

      <div id="invoer">
        <form method="post" action="">
        <label>Debiteur</label>
        <input type="text" name="deb_nmr" />
        <br />
        <label>Klantnaam</label>
        <input type="text" name="cost_name" />
        <br />
        <label>Aantal Pallets</label>
        <input type="text" name="numb_pallets" />
        <br />
        <label>Totaal Gewicht</label>
        <input type="text" name="tot_weight" />
        <br />
        <label>PB Nummers</label>
        <input type="text" name="PB's" />
        </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

Used the following Css:

```
label{
    display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;
}

.content{
    position: relative;

}

.invoer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Used info from W3school but can't get in to work. Found some more information on stack overflow, like using position relative and absolute. But the form stays in the upper left of the content div.

Comment: invoer element class doesn't exists. You got an element with id invoer, so your selector looks like #invoer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**content and invoer** are **ids** not **classes** so the correct way to use them is `#content ,#invoer` not `.Content , .content`.

> Everything is correct just replace the following css from this:

```
label{
    display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content{
    position: relative;

}

#invoer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

> to this:

```
label{
    display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content{
    position: relative;

}

#invoer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

> Here is the updated code.

```css
label{
    display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content{
    position: relative;

}

#invoer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="width:1280px ; height:800px">

  <div id="header" style=" background-color:#FFA500; width:1280px;height:200px">
    <h1>EXPORT ZENDINGEN</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:600px;width:700px;float:left;">

  </div>

  <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:600px;width:580px;float:right;">

    <div id="invoer">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <label>Debiteur</label>
        <input type="text" name="deb_nmr" />
        <br />
        <label>Klantnaam</label>
        <input type="text" name="cost_name" />
        <br />
        <label>Aantal Pallets</label>
        <input type="text" name="numb_pallets" />
        <br />
        <label>Totaal Gewicht</label>
        <input type="text" name="tot_weight" />
        <br />
        <label>PB Nummers</label>
        <input type="text" name="PB's" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="invoer">
```

But in css you tagged it as a class

```
.invoer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

However - change it to # and you should be able to style it.

```
#invoer{
  //some css
}
```